# How to move a label with the one next to it gets bigger

Tags: c#, label

I have 2 labels: Pics: [How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRtgL.png) | [When the users name gets bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9sC.png)

Basically one of them contains the user's name and the label next to it says whether they are online or offline.

The problem is: When the user's name gets bigger it will go over the other label and I'm trying to find out how to move the online label when the user's name label gets bigger so they don't overlap... any suggestions?

Comment: Set the `Left` property of the second label to the sum of the first label's `Left` and `Width` properties (plus a few extra pixels for some space)

Comment: Please state the technology (WPF, Winforms, Third Party Controls...)!

Answer (score 0):

If this is WinForms, you could use a FlowLayoutPanel and place both labels on that Panel.